# Terraform import error retrieving Virtual Machine Scale Set created from an image

Tags: import, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm trying to import a Linux VM Scale Set that was deployed in the Azure Portal from a custom shared image, also created in the portal. I'm using the following command:

*terraform import module.vm_scaleset.azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmscaleset /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/vmss1*

Import fails with the following error:

*Error: retrieving Virtual Machine Scale Set "vmss1" (Resource Group "myrg"): `properties.virtualMachineProfile.osProfile` was nil*

Below is my VM Scale set module code

```
data "azurerm_lb" "loadbalancer" {
  name                = var.lbName
  resource_group_name = var.rgName
}

data "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "addresspool" {
  loadbalancer_id = data.azurerm_lb.loadbalancer.id
  name            = var.lbAddressPool
}

data "azurerm_shared_image" "scaleset_image" {
  provider            = azurerm.ist
  name                = var.scaleset_image_name
  gallery_name        = var.scaleset_image_gallery
  resource_group_name = var.scaleset_image_rgname
}


resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "vmscaleset" {
  name                            = var.vmssName
  resource_group_name             = var.rgName
  location                        = var.location
  sku                             = var.vms_sku
  instances                       = var.vm_instances
  admin_username                  = azurerm_key_vault_secret.vmssusername.value
  admin_password                  = azurerm_key_vault_secret.vmsspassword.value
  disable_password_authentication = false
  zones                           = var.vmss_zones
  source_image_id                 = data.azurerm_shared_image.scaleset_image.id
  tags                            = module.vmss_tags.tags

  os_disk {
    storage_account_type = var.vmss_osdisk_storage
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    create_option        = "FromImage"
  }

  data_disk {
    storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
    caching              = "None"
    disk_size_gb         = 1000
    lun                  = 10
    create_option        = "FromImage"
  }

  network_interface {
    name                          = format("nic-%s-001", var.vmssName)
    primary                       = true
    enable_accelerated_networking = true

    ip_configuration {
      name                                   = "internal"
      load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids = [data.azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.addresspool.id]
      primary                                = true
      subnet_id                              = var.subnet_id
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags
    ]
  }
}
```

The source image was created from a Linux RHEL 8.6 VM that included a custom node.js script.
Examination of the Scale Set in the portal does indeed show that the virtualMachineProfile.osProfile is absent.

[image: vm scaleset json]

I haven't been able to find a solution on any forum. Is there any way to ignore the error and import the Scale Set anyway?

Comment: Which provider version are you using? Could that be an issue maybe?

Comment: I'm using hashicorp/azurerm v3.27.0

Comment: Do you have any upgrade mode defined?

Comment: Upgrade mode is Manual. I've been doing a bit more troubleshooting and I think it's to do with the admin_username.  I shouldn't be providing a username and pw when provisioning from a specialised image version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting-shared-images#creating-or-updating-a-vm-or-scale-sets-from-an-image-version.  So I need to figure out how to omit that - terraform complains when admin_username is omitted

Comment: looks like its related to this open issue https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/17331